# Create text string from character vector in R

Tags: r, string, vector, paste

I have character vectors of varying lengths and I would like to use them to create a formula for a regression model.

```
fifty <- c("AstheniaWeakness", "Breathlessness", "CT", "PatientAge")
```

The desired output would be:

```
Death ~ AstheniaWeakness + Breathlessness + CT + PatientAge
```

I have tried combinations of map and lapply with paste0 but these are not working.

Comment: `paste("Death ~", paste(fifty, collapse = " + "))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `reformulate`

```
reformulate(fifty, response = 'Death')
Death ~ AstheniaWeakness + Breathlessness + CT + PatientAge
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
paste("Death ~", paste(fifty, collapse = " + "))
# [1] "Death ~ AstheniaWeakness + Breathlessness + CT + PatientAge"
```

It's a two-step procedure: the first step combines the vector and collapses them with a particular string, `" + "`:

```r
paste(fifty, collapse = " + ")
# [1] "AstheniaWeakness + Breathlessness + CT + PatientAge"
```

then we need to prepend `"Death ~"` before that.